# Access other partitions with PHP and FTP

Tags: centos, php

I'm wondering how I can access another partition with PHP. I bought a new server and can see data the second hard drive is available but now I want to store the images users upload in that partition/hard drive but I have no idea how access this with PHP or FTP.

My website is at / and the hard drive I want use to use to store images is at /data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer here since i cannot comment (yet).

Since you tagged your post plesk, I assume you host your code using plesk which only uses your original root filesystem `/`. If you want to give an user access to `/data` you need to create a symlink in their home directory (somewhere here: `/var/www/vhost/yourdomain.com/httpdocs`).
Try something like this:

```
cd /data
mkdir myNewFolderForImages
# Create symlink in user folder
ln -s /data/myNewFolderForImages /var/www/vhost/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/imageUploadFolder
```

Now adapt your PHP-script so it saves the image files under `/var/www/vhost/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/imageUploadFolder`. If you login with the FTP-User of yourdomain.com you should also be able to browse the contents of the symlinked folder.

Make sure to set the corresponding permissions on `/data/myNewFolderForImages` and allow FollowSymLinks for Apache [see this post](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks)